# By using xpath, how to print the class name via selenium webdriver in eclipes

Tags: eclipse, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

How i print the class name 'section__form'  using the xpath of the class.

```
<body>
 <div class="main">
   <div class="order-summary-recap">
       <div class="wrap">
             <div id="checkout" class="current-step-shipping_and_payment_method" data-session-storage="">
                   <div id="contact-information" class="section step step--completed">
                         <div id="shipping-method" class="section step step--current">
                             <div class="section__header">
                             <div class="section__form">
                                 <div "shipping-msg">Wait while we fetch available shipping rates…</div>
                             <div class="section__summary"> </div>
                         </div>
                   </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can by using getAttribute:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='section__form']").getAttribute("class");
```

Comment: Well the given class name "section__form" is not static it depends on the value given by user on the form.

Comment: @Manish this is based on the html you have provided. If not we can go for  finding element using other locators like `className`, `id`, `cssSelector`

Comment: @Manish Good. Happy to help anytime :)